# SVN Configuration issue

Tags: asp.net, svn, tortoisesvn

I am new to configure SVN on my machine, When I am trying to configure my application/Project that is on SVN, using SVN Checkout, I am getting these errors.

1. Unable to open an ra_local session to the URL
2. Unable to open repository 'Path'
3. Expected FS format '2'; found format '4'

Please help

Thanks

Comment: You should supply information about the actual command you try to execute, the environment, versions etc.

Comment: @Hakon, I am just trying to configure project loacally, Right Clicking --> SVN Checkout...

Comment: you probably have incompatible SVN server and client version. try to update everything to the latest releases.

Comment: @Pint; Versions are same, anyother clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the answer to this question help?

[SVN Error: Expected fs format between '1' and '3'; found format '4'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838392/svn-error-expected-fs-format-between-1-and-3-found-format-4)