# TortoiseSVN doesn't connect to repository

Tags: tortoisesvn, cvs2svn

I've been using cvs2svn to migrate one of my repositories to SVN.

When I open it with TortoiseSVN, it gives me an error:

Expected FS format between '1' and '3'; found format '4'

what does that mean?

thank you.

Answer (score 5):

If you Google your exact error message, you get a number of good resources, first of all a [previous Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838392/svn-error-expected-fs-format-between-1-and-3-found-format-4).

Answer (score 0):

My first suspicion is the version of svn used in csv2svn is newer than the version of svn in TortoiseSVN...