# SVN migrate / dump local TortoiseSVN repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, migration, migrate, svndump

I have created an SVN repository on a Windows NAS with TortoiseSVN in Windows Explorer using the context-menu command "Create repository here". Now I want to migrate this repository into a proper SVN installation on an Apache Server on Debian. It is in fact the same computer where the repository is stored right now because the Linux server also acts as a Windows NAS (with Samba).

Now, if I run `svnadmin dump /path/to/repo > dump.bak` on the server, I get the error message: "Expected File System Format between 1 and 3; found 4".

I haven't installed SVN or Apache on my Windows computer and figure it wouldn't help me much because this non-standard File System Format is probably native to TortoiseSVN, right? However, I don't find an option to dump the repository directly with TortoiseSVN. 
Does someone know how to do that or is there another way to migrate the repository? Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is exactly what you want [SVN Error: Expected fs format between '1' and '3'; found format '4'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838392/svn-error-expected-fs-format-between-1-and-3-found-format-4)

Answer (score 1):

Your Tortise SVN tool probably created a version 4 repository, and the svnadmin tool came from an older installation of SVN which only understands versions 1 through 3.

Upgrade your svnadmin tool.

All SVN tools TortiseSVN, svnadmin, etc. use the same core libraries to access repositories, but they are released at specific (and often different) times.  If you use a tool which was released before the new repository revision was made, with SVN the tool reports an error that it cannot read the newer repository (instead of messing up your newer rev repository).