# svn: E180001: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, tortoisesvn, subversive

I have installed TortoiseSVN 1.8.0 (OS: Windows 7). I have created repository using TortoiseSVN in External Harddisk. Also i have added SVN plugin in Eclipse Juno. When i try to share my project via svn plugin to repository, it shows following message.

```
Share project was failed.
svn: E180001: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
svn: E180001: Unable to open repository 'file:///H:/Repository/MobileApplications/Android/Application/Source'
svn: E160043: Expected FS format between '1' and '5'; found format '6'.
```

Anyone can help me.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the answer to your question has been asked [here on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838392/svn-error-expected-fs-format-between-1-and-3-found-format-4)  It is best to make sure that your client is at the same revision as the server.  It looks like your client is too old for that server.  Make sure that the subclipse plugin version is is also 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

This Error said that FS format between SVN server(TortoiseSVN) and SVN client (Eclipse SVN plugin) is not equal. To fix this problem, go to repository path and change format version number.
The **format** file contain FS format version number:

```
x:\repos\db\format

6
layout sharded 1000
```

Replace 6 with 5 .