# How set local directory as SVN Repository in Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-luna

I install Subversion SVN Team Provider, Subversion SVN Team Provider Localization and SVNKit Library.
I Create local directory(D:\java\repository) and want use it as location for SVN repositor.
When I go to Window_>show view->other->svn->svn repository and choose New Repository Location, I must enter URL, but it won't proceed with this local above.
How can I set SVN so it will use this local directory as it's repository?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try entering in the **[New Location Wizard](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/teamSupport/new_location_wiz.php)** url field a local path following the `file:///` scheme:

```
file:///D/java/repository
```

That is also recommended in the [SVN Repository Dialog](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/teamSupport/create_repository.php).

> There is option to create a repository location for just created repository which uses `file:///` scheme (direct repository access). Accessible from '[SVN Repository View](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/teamSupport/repos_view.php)'.

Comment: I tried to share project to newly created repository, but got this:
svn: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL

Comment: @Error that would be a separate question (that is, if it hasn't been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17278061/6309, http://stackoverflow.com/a/23532180/6309)