# svn: E160043: Expected FS format between '1' and '4'; found format '6'

Tags: svn, repository, version, svnadmin

We get an error when my CLIENT is getting the list of our Subversion SERVER repository, like this;

```
D:\temp>svn list svn://192.168.1.2/d:/svnrepository/r0
svn: E160043: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn://192.168.1.2/d:/svnrepository/r0'
svn: E160043: Expected FS format between '1' and '4'; found format '6'
```

and CLIENT has svn version 1.8.3 (r1516576)

```
D:\temp>svn --version
svn, version 1.8.3 (r1516576)
compiled Aug 27 2013, 19:43:20 on x86-microsoft-windows
```

and our SERVER svn and svnandmin version is same;

```
d:\>svnadmin  --version
svnadmin, version 1.8.3 (r1516576)
compiled Aug 27 2013, 19:43:20 on x86-microsoft-windows

d:\>svn --version
svn, version 1.8.3 (r1516576)
compiled Aug 27 2013, 19:43:20 on x86-microsoft-windows
```

What is the problem in this sutiation? 
(apologize to poor english)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SVN Error: Expected fs format between '1' and '3'; found format '4'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838392/svn-error-expected-fs-format-between-1-and-3-found-format-4)

Answer (score 1):

Your svn-client, even it was upgraded to 1.8, declare itself as older version (1.6 ?)

You **must to reboot** Windows at least once before using *this* client

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem.  My subversion server was running when I updated it, so the svnserve file was never updated.  SvnServe is what allows you to use the `svn://` protocol.  These steps should all the done on your server.

1) Stop the svnserve.exe service (or kill your process)

2) Uninstall subversion

3) Install the latest subversion client.  I used Subversion 1.8.3 (Windows 64-bit) found at http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion

4) Start the svnserve.exe service