# svn E160043: Expected FS format between '1' and '4'; found format '6'

Tags: svn, ssh

I want my project to be shared by different computers. As I don't have a server, I decided to create a svn repository on my mac.

I followed this tutorial
http://www.civicactions.com/blog/2010/may/25/how_set_svn_repository_7_simple_steps

After importing my project, the checkout test fails :

```
svn co svn+ssh://myusername@myIPaddress:absolute_path_of_my_repository
svn: E160043: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn+ssh://MYUSERNAME@myIPaddress/absolute_path_of_my_repository'
svn: E160043: Expected FS format between '1' and '4'; found format '6'
```

It can not be a version conflict problem as (for now) only one computer is involved. For information, both svn --version and svnadmin --version return "version 1.8.10"

Thank you by advance for your time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SVN Error: Expected fs format between '1' and '3'; found format '4'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838392/svn-error-expected-fs-format-between-1-and-3-found-format-4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link solved my problem : https://code.google.com/p/svnx/issues/detail?id=41

Answer (score 1):

A more specific answer is posted at: https://subversion.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=3&viewType=browseAll&dsMessageId=520236#messagefocus

Comment: Can you add a short summary of the answer, just in case the link stops working in the future?